# Координаты в ключ ассоциативного массива

Tags: массивы, хеширование, координаты

Имеются координаты вида (x; y) - целые числа. Их необходимо преобразовать в уникальное значение, что бы использовать в качестве ключа в ассоциативном массиве. Вроде хеш-функции. Лучше что бы уникальное значение было так же целым числом

Сложение, вычитание координат, AND, OR, XOR, ++, битовые сдвиги, как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871379/7485582  https://stackoverflow.com/q/892618/7485582

Comment: А что Вы так храните? Просто интересно. Точнее даже так: для чего такая структура, как Вы ей будете пользоваться, что-то искать?

Comment: К первому числу прибавьте тысяч сто и сложите со вторым. Будет уникальное число в некотором смысле. Если конечно ваши числа не большие. И в JS нет целых чисел, все просто Number а не int.

Comment: Используя алгоритм A* необходимо выяснять у карты какие клетки являются непроходимыми (например). Непроходимыми являются лишь некоторые их них. Что бы не хранить и не опрашивать лишние нули, думаю просто хранить непроходимые клетки в ассоциативном массиве, и сразу опрашивать массив по координатам (ключу из координат).

Comment: Как оказалось, побитовые операторы в JS интерпретируют операнды как последовательность из 32 битов (нулей и единиц). Они производят операции, используя двоичное представление числа, и возвращают новую последовательность из 32 бит (число) в качестве результата. Что происходит при сношении таких чисел со стандартными в JS, кто там в кого когда превращается ещё предстоит выяснить